# Should old questions be auto-locked for new users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, locks

*I know this has most likely been covered before but if not:*

Has the community considered implementing a system to "lock" old questions that already have answers to new users?

Honestly, I don't know why this is a issue but still every day the front page has at least a few questions that have been bumped by some new-ish ( <50 rep) user posting "their way" of doing exactly what the answer says on a old, more or less dead post.

I know that I'm new to meta and I may be over-stepping my bounds but I would suggest something like disallowing users with less then 50 rep to post on questions more then 6 months old with already selected answers (or at least ones that have been inactive for 6 months).

This would ensure we are not cutting off new user's options for posting too much as they can still post in active or unanswered questions and yet it would massively reduce that number of junk posts and necro'd questions.

Comment: See: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/how-do-we-handle-duplicate-answers

Comment: What about old insufficiently-answered posts, how many of them have something valuable added?  I'd like to know the downsides of this option before supporting it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see very little damage in new users answering old questions.  This is an easy and "safe" feeling way for a user to start transitioning from lurker to active participant, and the cost of having a question bumped is pretty low.  We don't want to encourage repetitive answers, but we don't need to forcefully prevent them either.

Attempting to lock old questions would cause a lot of problems too, as old questions frequently do get out of date, and new users searching the existing question base are the most likely to notice and be able to immediately contribute by posting an improved answer.